# Jetty Seems to Ignore Port Argument

Tags: java, jetty

I'm working through some Spring MVC examples, and using Jetty jetty-9.1.1.v20140108 as my dev server.  I have another server, JBOSS 5.1.0 listening on port 8080, so I tried to specify an alternate port for Jetty, however, it didnt seem to "stick".  What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ java -Djetty.port=9000 -jar start.jar

...

INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-example': initialization completed in 142 ms
2014-02-05 17:27:50.369:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@45ad71f0{/spring-example,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spring-example.war-_spring-example-any-1672792505692467455.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/spring-example.war}
2014-02-05 17:27:50.374:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@228643af{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
...
```

Maybe there is another port setting that takes priority, but I would think the command line would trump all.  How do I set the port correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you set port as an application argument not a system property: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html

java -jar start.jar jetty.port=9000

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it, and thanks for the link to the documentation.